# Mongodb create index with flask mongokit extension

Tags: python, indexing, flask, pymongo, mongokit

I'm trying to create an index with a flask-mongokit connection:

```
db = MongoKit(app)
db.mydatabase.users.create_index("email", unique=True)
```

But it throws this error at me:

```
...
host=ctx.app.config.get('MONGODB_HOST'),
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'
```

If I use Pymongo directly instead:

```
conn = MongoClient()
conn.mydatabase.users.create_index("email", unique=True)
```

Everithing works fine!

The problem is that I don't want to manage a pymongo's connection but instead use the one created by the mongokit extension.

Comment: Where is `ctx` being defined?

Comment: I didn't define ctx since pymongo works without me having to define it

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, it seems that **mongokit doesn't support index creation since version 7.x**, they really should remove index creation from the official documentation.

https://github.com/namlook/mongokit/issues/98